# How to set time interval to button_click in C# windows form application

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Here the below code enables the particular bit as high in parallel port.How to set time interval for the button click in windows form.If i set the time interval to 2 seconds the timer should start then 2 seconds after that it should stop automatically.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PortAccess.Output(888,1);

    }
```

can u please let me know any suggestion or example to do this.Inside this button_click.

Comment: I can't figure out what you want to do. Why do you need a timer? 2 seconds delay for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just want to clear the bit 2 seconds later? Something like this should work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Prevent multiple button clicks
    button.Enabled = false;
    PortAccess.Output(888, 1);
    Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = 2000 };
    timer.Tick += HandleTimerTick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void HandleTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = (Timer) sender;
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Dispose();
    button.Enabled = true;
    PortAccess.Output(888, 0);
}
```

You may find it simpler to set up the timer just once, and store it as an instance variable. Then you could attach the `Tick` event and set the interval on construction, and add it to the components of the form so that it's automatically disposed. Your methods would then be:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button.Enabled = false;
    PortAccess.Output(888, 1);
    timer.Start();
}

private void HandleTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    button.Enabled = true;
    PortAccess.Output(888, 0);
}
```